# show row depending what radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have read through a number of similar questions on stackoverflow but am a little lost of how to modify it to my particular situation. I want to output 2 rows in html differently depending what radio button is selected. I am still learning javascript...

What am i missing please? and how do i get the html to output directly after the radio button form item?

My form looks like this;

```
<tr>
  <td>Select your option</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="your_store" id="store_yes" value="1" onclick = "addrow()" />
  <?php echo $text_yes; ?>
  <input type="radio" name="your_store" id="store_no" value="0" onclick = "addrow()" />
  <?php echo $text_no; ?></td>
</tr>
```

After this i also have several other form items

At the bottom of the form i have the function;

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
function addrow() {   
  if(document.getElementById('store_yes').checked) {
    html  = '<tr>'; 
    html  = '<td>Row is showing this</td> '; 
    html  = '</tr>'; 
  } else {
    html  = '<tr>';
    html  = '<td>Row is showing something else</td> '; 
    html  = '</tr>'; 
  }
//--></script>
```

**EDIT**, if YES is selected the 2 rows appear, the rows need to dissapear again if NO is then subsequently selected, ie change of users mind.

Comment: You cannot append a `tr` element after your `input` element, not unless you want valid HTML (and you do), since you would then have table rows inside table cells. What do you want to add exactly?

Comment: @Mario I want to add 2 more form fields after the radio buttons. If button is set to yes, extra fields show, if set to no, they are hidden form items with set values.

Comment: @Mark There are few other ways of doing. You don't have to add the elements dynamically. You could just change the css display property for the elements on a particular event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code, I have used Jquery to append the rows to the end of your table. Read more [about .append() in jquery here](http://api.jquery.com/append/) .

The modified function:

```
function addrow() {
    if (document.getElementById('store_yes').checked) {
        $('#yourTable').append('<tr><td>Row is showing this</td></tr>');
    } else {
        $('#yourTable').append('<tr><td>Row is showing something else</td></tr>');
    }
}
```

The modified HTML

`

```
<table border="1" id="yourTable"><tr>
  <td>Select your option</td>
  <td><input type="radio" name="your_store" id="store_yes" value="1" onclick = "addrow()" />
    <input type="radio" name="your_store" id="store_no" value="0" onclick = "addrow()" />
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

`

[Check out the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/cULH3/6/)

**Update** 
The demo has been updated to remove appended rows if the user changes his mind

Comment: @awahm, thanks, however if the user changes their mind, pressing the radio will append another row again and again. Is is possible to reset the table to original before appending another?

Comment: Yes, its possible, you could check if a row has been added previously and remove the row if so. You do it very time the function is called.  [Here is an updated function](http://jsfiddle.net/cULH3/6/) . Do some Googling, there is a lot of help out there ;) Cheers!